# Im having trouble using the time package

Tags: time, python-3.x

whenever I use the time package, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\2015\intrest calculator.py", line 53, in <module>
    time.sleep(1)
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'sleep'
```

here is my code:

```
    import time 

    while True:
        choice = input("will you like to calculate simple or compound intrest:")
        if choice == "simple intrest":
            userData(choice)
            time = time/12 
            intrest = principal * time * intrestRate
            intrest = round(intrest, 2)
            balance = principal + intrest
            balance = round(balance, 2) 
            balance = str(balance)
            intrest = str(intrest)
            print("your intrest is: %" + intrest) 
            time.sleep(1)  

            print("your final balance is $" + balance)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry guys, just figured out my mistake.

for anyone else having the same problem, make sure that none of your variables are the same as any of your packages.

Sorry guys, it was my bad.

should have seen that from the beginning